# Access to the path "" is denied

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I know this question has been asked so many times, but my problem is different. I am developing a web app with windows authentication and impersonation turned on. I am logged in to my computer as `domain\user`. In this application I am just creating a directory called `newDir` inside a network computer directory, say, `\\computerName\myFolder`. I have full access control to this directory. When I explicitly enter my username and password as `<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\user" password="pass">` in `web.config` file and run the application it does not prompt for the username and password, instead it creates the directory in the specified directory as expected. But when I remove username and password from `identity` element leaving `impersonation` turned on and run the application, it prompts for the username and password but does not accept the same username and password which I removed from the `identity` element in `web.config` file and sometimes it does not prompt for the username and password, just shows the exception page `access to the path "\\computerName\myFolder\newDir" is denied`.

For testing I have added a line to check that under which username the code is running:

`Response.Write(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + "<br/>");`

It prints out the same `domain\user` username.

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like using impersonation to access a UNC path vs. a local path is a special case. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx, "If the application resides on a UNC share, ASP.NET always impersonates the IIS UNC token to access that share unless a configured account is used. If you provide an explicitly configured account, ASP.NET uses that account in preference to the IIS UNC token."

This answer [UNC access whilst using impersonation asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120829/unc-access-whilst-using-impersonation-asp-net) also has some pointers.

It sounds like you may be limited to one user for accessing the UNC users - either one configured in web.config, the app pool identity or the one you pick for delegation.

Comment: For security reasons, Windows authentication does not provide the web server with the user's username and password in plain text, so the web server is unable to authenticate as the user over the network.  (Theoretically, impersonation within a domain is possible via Kerberos delegation, but that's more complicated and I guess ASP.NET doesn't support it.)